# Django add single fields to Model form using AJAX call

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Model form. The form contains a button "Add more Field". Clicking this button sends an AJAX call which  should add a textfield to the form. Any number of "textfields" can be added.

I am not sure if Django-Formsets is the correct way to do it as I need to store the data of "extra added fields" in the same Model Form's Table in the database.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this recently, and my solution was to subclass the form dynamically, providing only the field needed, and rendering just that field:

```
from forms import SomeModelForm
from models import SomeModel
def view_name(request,pk,field):
    SomeModelFieldForm(SomeModelForm):
        class Meta(SomeModelForm.Meta):
            fields = (field,)

    inst = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = SomeModelFieldForm(instance=inst)

    #the rest of your view goes here...

    #...send only the form's field:
    ctx = {'field': form[field]}
    return render_to_response("template",ctx)
```

This takes advantage of your original form's specifics - i.e., if you have specially defined widgets, or other restrictions, or something.  It then restricts the entire form to a single field.  This is to allow the validation of a single field on an existing model.

However, you don't want to send the entire form, you only want to send the single field. `form[field]` is a `django.forms.forms.BoundField` that represents the specific field  you pass in.

For example, if you were working with the `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`, and you created a form for a specifi user, in idle calling `form["username"]` would return:

```
<django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x01354750>
```

and calling  `print form["username"]` would print:

```
<input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" value="name_of_user" maxlength="30" />
```

Comment: I didn't get it . Could you please elaborate upon it ? What is form[field] ?